# Docker, Laradock, PhpStorm, WSL2, Xdebug configuration

Tags: docker, phpstorm, xdebug, laradock

I've got a problem with connect my Xdebug:

> Xdebug: [Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: host.docker.internal:9000 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).

I'm running PhpStorm from WSL. Also I'm using Laradock and I don't know how  to configure it.

This is my xdebug.ini inside laradock/workspace:

```ini
xdebug.remote_host="host.docker.internal"
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM

xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_enable=0
xdebug.cli_color=0
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="~/xdebug/phpstorm/tmp/profiling"

xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req

xdebug.var_display_max_children=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_data=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=-1
```

I'm not sure about **xdebug.remote_host**.

This is my settings in PhpStorm. Can someone please help me with that I'm trying since Monday to configure it properly.

[image]

I'm expecting properly working Xdebug. I tried to add into `remote_host` my Windows IP, my WSL IP, and `host.docker.internal`.

Comment: You need to read the upgrade guide, as all settings that you're making are for Xdebug 2: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide

Comment: 2 tips, besides Derick's tip, which is great: 1) Do **NOT**use port 9000, 2) Start phpStorm first and then start Laradock. In general: there are a **lot** of settings you need to make, but let's get PHP version, port number right

Comment: How did you install Docker? As Docker Desktop, or as a package in the WSL machine?
Also, please clarify what `I running PhPStorm from wsl` means - do you really run PhpStorm in the WSL machine, or do you run it locally on Windows and then just open a project via a `\\wsl$` / `\\wsl.localhost` path?

Comment: I Installed phpstorm inside wsl and i running it from there, and yes I installed docker desktop I changed port to 9300 but no work

Answer (score 0):

Xdebug cannot connect to PhpStorm because:

1. You installed Docker as Docker Desktop on Windows
2. PhpStorm is running in WSL

When you use Docker Desktop, `host.docker.internal` sends you to the host, the Windows machine.
Since PhpStorm is running in WSL and not on the host, there's nothing listening on the 9000/9003 ports in Windows, and that is why there's no connection.

Instead of `host.docker.internal`, you can set `xdebug.remote_host` to the IP of the WSL machine.
For me, setting it to the IP  of the `eth0` interface worked; you can get it by running `ip a` in the WSL terminal.

If it still doesn't work after that, it makes sense to check the [Xdebug remote log](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#collect-xdebug-logs).